# How to read a PDF into a memory stream?

Tags: c#

How can I read a `PDF` file into a `memory stream` such that I can save it to DB in a `"Text"` column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you MUST use a text field, you can read the file as a byte array, convert that to a base64 string, and store that in the text field:

```
string fileString = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
```

or if you have an actual file on disk:

```
string fileString = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(@"path\to\file.pdf"));
```

Comment: one question: What is Base64 for? Is it to make it compatible with Text type ?

Comment: Base64 is an encoding scheme that allows you to represent binary data as a string. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Answer (score 3):

One option is to convert the file into byte array as below and then store it in db in a `varbinary` column.

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("<pdfFile>");
```

I would prefer storing the file on a file server or some folder and then just store the file path in db.

Comment: I said the column type is "TEXT"...TEXT" ... not VARBINARY

Comment: Well, if the db schema cant be changed, then it may be stored in `text` column but it has to be converted back to binary when you are returning from db.

Comment: Ok..How? Can you update your answer?

Comment: The query which returns the Text column could be `select cast(cast(t.TextColumn as varchar(max)) as varbinary(max)) from TextToVarbinary T` or the conversion can be done on the front end too.

Answer (score 2):

You can read any binary file to byte array and then convert it to base64 with `Convert.ToBase64String`. The resulting string can be stored to db as text. When you need to decode it back to byte array use FromBase64String.